# Font-face isn't working in Firefox

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, font-face

I have added a font to a site, added the CSS and uploaded the font files and it is working in IE but not in Firefox. Why is that?

**CSS:**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFont';
    src: url('MyFont.eot');
    src: url('MyFont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('MyFont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('MyFont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('MyFont.svg#MyFontRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

label { font-family: 'MyFont'; font-size: 20px; }
```

The `label` was just a test, but it's working. The font files are in the same directory as the CSS.

I've tried almost everything, and its still not working....

Does anybody know what's wrong? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Check Firebug to see if the fonts actually loaded.  You may need to add the MIME types in your web server's config (.htaccess, web.config).

Comment: no warnings/errors in firebug, and IE loads the font, so its a bit wired.. alltho, i dont have access to the .htaccess files ect..

Comment: No warning, but did any of the font files actually load?  You can see that under *Net* in Firebug (or in a tool like Fiddler).  That would sort out whether it's a rendering issue, or if your web server just isn't serving the file.

Comment: Yes, the .ttf file is getting loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out there was another CSS file, overwriting the one i made.

Problem solved

Answer (score 2):

In order:

1. Check if the font is on [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts). If it is, use that version, don't embed your self (for ease of use, caching, browser update compat. etc.)
2. If not, then check your MIMEs. To do this, use Firebug's Net panel to look at the headers and check they are correct.
3. If the MIME is wrong, then fix it using either .htaccess, or by writing a PHP file that uses file_get_contents() and header() to fix it.

Comment: The font aint on google, since its a paied font, and special made for the site. How do i check if the MIME's are correct ? AND, theres a wired thing here i just saw in the Net panel.. in the response, i can see the css, witch is fine, but the link to the font aint correst. Ive cleared the cache and reloaded the site, but they are still there